# Add noise to multiple columns with different means and std in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, statistics

I have a DataFrame of float type values containing about 80 000 rows and 100 different features, each one with a very different distribution than the other (different means and std). It is a timeseries dataset.

**How can I add noise to my dataset in order to augment the data while taking into account the different feature distributions? I want to add noise to only the 45 first columns of the DataFrame**

I want to take into account the fact that each column has a different mean and std (maybe scale the noise?) and not just add a general Gaussian noise df to mine. Also, do you advice to add/remove outliers ?

Thanks a lot.

Python 3.11

Answer (score 1):

You can probably try:

```
import numpy as np

# select first 45 columns
N = 45
cols = df.columns[:N]

# add random noise with a deviation per column
df[cols] += np.random.normal(scale=df[cols].std(), size=(len(df), N))
```

Comment: Won't this just add a dataframe with the same std over the entire dataframe?

Comment: @Perrupi no, this will add a random value scaled with a different std per column.

Comment: Is it possible that the mean is also scaled differently per column? I just tried the code and I think it is adding to much noise

Comment: Yes you can: `np.random.normal(loc=df[cols].mean(), scale=df[cols].std(), size=(len(df), N))`, but the mean is probably not a good parameter, this won't change the spread, it will just shift your noise up/down. Rather add a factor: `scale=df[cols].std()*factor`